# can I get firestore error code when using Source.Server but user is not connected to internet?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have an error message like this if the user is not connected to internet, I set the source to be Source.Server:

> failed to get document from server. (However, this document does exist
>   in the local cache. Run again without setting to SERVER to retrieve
>   the cached document.)

I want to write my own error message, I can actually hard code the message, something like this

```
if (message == "failed to get document from server ........") {
   showToast("showing my own message here")
}
```

but it can easily break, if for example, firebase sdk change the error message string. is there any error code or enum error to identify this ?

here is the code

```
fun getUserData(source: Source = Source.SERVER, userID: String, completion: (user: User?, errorMessage:String?) -> Unit) {

        db.document("users/${userID}").get(source).addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->

            if (documentSnapshot == null || !documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                completion(null,"Account is not found")
                return@addOnSuccessListener
            }

            val userData = documentSnapshot.data ?: return@addOnSuccessListener
            val user = User(userData)
            completion(user,null)


        }.addOnFailureListener {
            completion(null,it.localizedMessage) // error message comes from here
        }


    }
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the code of the query and how you are handling its results (not just checking the message)?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated my question. thank you very much

Comment: @DougStevenson currently I just want to show my own message for error handling by using toast in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception delivered to your failure listener callback is of type [FirebaseFirestoreException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException). That class contains a formal [Code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.html) type that determines the exact error.  I can't tell which one it would be, but I best you could figure out by examining the results.  If there isn't actually a code for some reason, try filing an issue on [the Firebase SDK GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk).

Comment: but I can't access that formal code like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwmGt.png, I can't find getCode() as shown in the documentation. so how to get the code ?

Comment: Check and cast the exception to FirebaseFirestoreException.